# How do I check the value of a foreign key on insert?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm teaching myself SQL using Sqlite3, well suited for my forever-game project (Don't we all have one?) and have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE equipment_types (
    row_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    type TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO equipment_types (type) VALUES ('gear'), ('weapon');

CREATE TABLE equipment_names (
    row_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE);

INSERT INTO equipment_names (name) VALUES ('club'), ('band aids');

CREATE TABLE equipment (
    row_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES equipment_names,
    type INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES equipment_types);

INSERT INTO equipment (name, type) VALUES (1, 2), (2, 1);
```

So now we have a `'club'` that is a `'weapon'`, and `'band aids'` that are `'gear'`. I now want to make a `weapons` table; it will have an `equipment_id` that references the `equipment` table and weapon properties like damage and range, etc. I want to constrain it to equipment that is a `'weapon'` type.

But for the life of me I can't figure it out. `CHECK`, apparently, only allows expressions, not subqueries, and I've been trying to craft a `TRIGGER` that might do the job, but in short, I can't quite figure out the query and syntax, or how to check the result that as I understand it will be in the form of a table, or null.

Also, are there good online resources for learning SQL more advanced than W3School? Add them as a comment, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write a query that looks up the type belonging to the new record:

```
CREATE TRIGGER only_weapons
BEFORE INSERT ON weapons
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (SELECT et.type
      FROM euqipment_types AS et
      JOIN equipment AS e ON e.type = et.equipment_type_id
      WHERE e.row_id = NEW.equipment_id
     ) != 'weapon' 
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "not a weapon");
END;
```

Comment: Thank you, I was getting snared up on syntax, and a little bit on joins across transitive tables. Comparing your code to the SQLite3 documentation, it seems obvious in hind sight.

Answer (score -1):

The foreign key references should be to the primary key and to the same time.  I would phrase this as:

```
CREATE TABLE equipment_types (
    equipment_type_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    type TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO equipment_types (type) VALUES ('gear'), ('weapon');

CREATE TABLE equipment_names (
    equipment_name_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT INTO equipment_names (name) VALUES ('club'), ('band aids');


CREATE TABLE equipment (
    equipment_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    equipment_name_id INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES equipment_names(equipment_name_id),
    equipement_type_id INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES equipment_types(equipement_type_id)
);
```

I would not use the name `row_id` for the primary key.  That is the built-inn default, so the name is not very good.  In SQLite, an integer primary key is automatically auto-incremented (see [here](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)).

Comment: I'll be sure to follow the convention in my actual code.

Comment: `row_id` isn't the same name; the built-in/default name is `rowid`, which can also be referenced as `_rowid_` or `oid` (as per the link). Even still it's a moot point as `???? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` defines an alias for `rowid` anyway. Probably very rare but there could be a potential use (if it works) of using `rowid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` to circumvent rowid's being changed by the `VACUUM` command (although the correct/sure way would be to use another name other than `rowid`, `_rowid_` or `oid`);